# Fetching values from sql 2005 using vbscript

Tags: sql, vbscript, asp-classic

I am designing a web page that will fetch records for a specific id and print the information.I am just trying to redirect user to other page if provided id does not exists.I tried the below code but when id is null its showing blank page instead of redirecting to desired page.

code:

```
<% 
Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.ConnectionString= "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=eseva;Data Source=BHAGWAT-PC"
conn.open
set rs=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
rs.Open "Select * from saat_bara where id='"&request.form("t1")&"'" , conn

if IsNull(rs.Fields("id").Value) then
  response.redirect("end.asp")
else
  while not rs.eof
    response.Write("Token no:")
    response.Write(rs.fields.item(0))
    response.write("<br><br>")

    response.Write("Name:")
    response.Write(rs.fields.item(1))
    response.write("<br><br>")

    response.Write("Address:")
    response.Write(rs.fields.item(2))
    response.write("<br><br>")

    response.Write("Bdate:")
    response.Write(rs.fields.item(3))
    response.write("<br><br>")
    rs.movenext
  wend
end if
%>
```

Comment: Someone should have pointed out that you should not pass variables directly into a SQL Server query unless you know where they are coming from and when you pass `Request.QueryString` or `Request.Form` you are not in control of what is sent. What is stopping someone from posting malicious code into your database? This topic is discussed over and over on SO I myself have posted umptine answers to this very topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't check a field that does not exist against null. So:

```
rs.Open "Select * from saat_bara where id='"&request.form("t1")&"'" , conn
if rs.eof
   response.redirect("end.asp")
else
   while not rs.eof
   ...
end if
```

Comment: Why you encouraging this? Two words Parameterised Queries.

Comment: The question wasn't *Please rewrite my program the way you think best*. The OP had a specific issue and Ekkehard answered it. I can find a number of mistakes in your code as well, @Lankymart. Though you have some good suggestions, be careful not to assume what the best code is. Personally, if I was going to clean his code, the first thing I would have done is get rid of the 12 consecutive Response.Write() statements within a record loop!

Comment: @Bond That's not the same, anything that answers the question but encourages bad practice I cannot abide, there is no excuse except ignorance for not using parameterised queries. As for the Response.Writes I agree but then again that is not a security risk. My other suggestions are purely based on years of experience with using SQL server and asp-classic if I can help above and beyond I will do.

Comment: @Lankymart I don't think it's encouraging bad practice. It's using the OP's code for demonstration. You risk confusing the OP even more by completely changing everything. We need to stay on topic. Your answer (and your comment above) don't relate to the OP's question. As for pointing out security risks only, I don't see how #2 or #3 in your answer are security risks. They're performance boosts. And if you're going to point out performance boosts, then why not eliminate the `Response.Write()` statements in a recordset loop, which will likely be the slowest part of his script?

Comment: @Lankymart Hey man, you were obviously trying to help and we all appreciate that. But I don't think we can be too critical of Ekkehard for *just* answering the OP's question and not teaching him all the best practices of ADO.

Comment: @Bond I wasn't saying his answer is wrong his answer is bag on the money, I just think he should have pointed out the inherent risk in coding it that way. But this isn't just about [tag:ado] these principles to [tag:.net] and other programming languages just as much.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48769/discussion-between-lankymart-and-bond)

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Listed somethings you may want to consider for the future;

1. Look into using the `ADODB.Command` object to build parameterised queries.

   - Protects against SQL Injection
   - Data type negotiation is done for you (no adding apostrophes in your query when dealing with string types).
   - No need to manual setup `ADODB.Connection` and close it as `.ActiveConnection` can take a connection string and build your `ADODB.Connection` for you and when your `ADODB.Command` is released so is the associated connection.
2. Return only the field you need in your SQL query instead of using `SELECT *` depending on the table size this can be very costly (in your code your only returning four fields).
3. If you are just displaying data to screen consider using `.GetRows()` to return an `Array` rather than using `ADODB.Recordset` for iterating through your returned resultset. Resources that would be otherwise used by the `ADODB.Recordset` can be released as all your data is contained in a 2 dimensional array.

Below is an example of your code using `ADODB.Command` and Arrays;

```vb
<%
Dim connstr, sql, cmd, rs, data
Dim row, rows

connstr = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=eseva;Data Source=BHAGWAT-PC"

sql = ""
sql = sql & "SELECT Field0, Field1, Field2, Field3 " & vbCrLf
sql = sql & "FROM saat_bara " & vbCrLf
sql = sql & "WHERE id = ?"

Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
With cmd
  .ActiveConnection = connstr
  .CommandType = adCmdText
  .CommandText = sql
  'As you put apostrophes around your id assumed it must be a varchar. If
  'this is used as your primary key would be more efficient for it to be
  'a numeric type like int, in which case you would use adInteger.
  .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@id", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50)
  Set rs = .Execute(, Array(Request.Form("t1")))
  If Not rs.EOF Then data = rs.GetRows()
  'Release memory used by recordset
  Call rs.Close()
  Set rs = Nothing
End With
'Release memory and close connection used by command.
Set cmd = Nothing

If IsArray(data) Then
  rows = UBound(data, 2)
  For row = 0 To rows
    'Consider not using Response.Write in your loop (taken from Bond's suggestion)
    Call Response.Write("Token no:")
    Call Response.Write(data(0, row))
    Call Response.Write("<br><br>")

    Call Response.Write("Name:")
    Call Response.Write(data(1, row))
    Call Response.Write("<br><br>")

    Call Response.Write("Address:")
    Call Response.Write(data(2, row))
    Call Response.Write("<br><br>")

    Call Response.Write("Bdate:")
    Call Response.Write(data(3, row))
    Call Response.Write("<br><br>")
  Next
Else
  'No data redirect
  Call Response.Redirect("end.asp")
End If
%>
```